# Media queries for iPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, media-queries

Everyone.
I did a website and I got only problem with iPhones. I can't make work my website properly on those devices. I have tried different solutions which we can find on stackoverflow like:

```
@media (device-height : 568px) 
   and (device-width : 320px) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

@media
    only screen and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (min-device-width: 960px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (min-device-height: 560px),
    only screen and (max-device-height: 1136px) and (min-device-height: 960px) and (max-device-width: 640px) and (min-device-width: 560px) {
    /* iPhone only */
}

@media only screen 
    and (max-device-width: 640px), 
    only screen and (max-device-width: 667px), 
    only screen and (max-width: 480px)
{ }
```

But nothing helped me
My queries for iphone and other devices are so

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2), screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 736px) and (max-resolution: 401dpi)
    .l-wrapper
        flex-direction: column
        .l-item
            width: 100%

    .projects
        figure.project
            width: 100%
            margin-right: 0

    .edu-places
        .edu-place
            span
                &.period
                    padding-top: 3em

                    &:before
                        top: 3em
    .h-wrapper
        flex-direction: column
        align-items: center

@media screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2), screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 736px) and (max-resolution: 401dpi)
    #wrapper
        flex-direction: column

    #header
        flex: 1

    #main
        flex: 1
```

It works properly everywhere I need except iPhones. What I should do? Looking for your help and advices.

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:320px){styles here}